# wget, epoch time & GET requests

Tags: wget, epoch

I need to be able to mimic the following `GET` request using wget however am unsure how to do so.

I also need to be able to set the epoch of the day the script is executed with the start time of 12:01 a.m. and the end time of 11.59 p.m. So as example the date of 2014/01/16 (YYYY/MM/DD) and the time of 12:01 a.m. would be 1400241660

The request needs to have the following keys.

```
Key
Request
Accept
Referer
Accept-Language
Accept-Encoding
User-Agent
Host
DNT
Connection
Cookie
```

with the following values where the appropriate epoch time is appended for the start and end date time.

```
Value
GET /Archive.cgi?cmd=query&ca=255&start_time=1400284860&end_time=1400371140&dst=2&level=0&username=QWRtaW4=&rnd=6812 HTTP/1.1
*/*
http://192.168.1.199:8080/export.html
en-us
gzip, deflate
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; MAARJS)
192.168.1.199:8080
1
Keep-Alive
MosaLanguage=0; DUserName=QWRtaW4%3D; DPassword=MDAwMDAw; session=
```

**EDIT**

At the suggestion of Martin, i tried the following cURL command but all i get is 404

```
curl -c cookie.txt --url "http://192.168.1.199:8080/Archive.cgi?" --data "cmd=query&ca=255&start_time=1400284860&end_time=1400371140&dst=2&level=0&username=QWRtaW4=&rnd=681"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into CURL, it can do exactly what you need with regard to cookies, headers, etc... I'm not sure wget can.

Comment: Do you have an example especially when setting epoch time?

Comment: To get 12:01am of the current day use

`date -d 'today 12:01' +%s`

Getting 11:59pm works the same

Comment: I can't find any working example of setting cookies,headers,etc

Comment: wget has some header support which you can use to pass cookies. Google for wget manual. You'd need something like

`wget --header="Cookie MosaLanguage=0" --header="Accept-Charset: iso-8859-2" http://www.website/archive.cgi?etc...`

Comment: Thanks. I did Google it however did not come across examples for multiple cookie values or some of the other key values. Also the example you gave me is of `wget` and not `cURL`.

Comment: Try

`curl -c cookie.txt http://192.168.1.199:8080/Archive.cgi?cmd=query&ca=255&start_time=1400284860&end_time=1400371140&dst=2&level=0&username=QWRtaW4=&rnd=681`

Comment: What does `curl http://192.168.1.199:8080` give you? A 404 would mean the page could not be found. Also, my curl command differs slightly from the one you are using.

Comment: It returns the contents of the page